# in-app Consume subscriptions by user Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

i have an app which have to login to enjoy the features i have a premium subscription but the susbscription aplies to every user use the app i want to get subscribers by user and not by app

this is what i try do achieve:

```
user 1 -> premium subscription
user 2 -> adfree subscription
user 3 -> free
```

this is what is happening at the moment:

```
user 1 -> adfree subscription
user 2 -> adfree subscription
user 3 -> adfree subscription
```

how to achieve this?
im using https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

Comment: How are you determining what kind of subscription the user has?  That's where the problem is, so let's see that code.

Comment: i want to mange subscriptions and purchases by user and not by email registered by google

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, IAB is based on gmail accounts and not based on users. You would have to devise your own logic for this kind of behavior, using a backend server. A general idea from the top of my head is:

1. Buy an in-app product using a gmail account.
2. Call your own server's API and register this orderId for this particular user that is active and store this information on the server.
3. Next time when the app is active, check for all the purchases for this gmail account.
4. Call your own server to check for active purchases/subscriptions for this active user.
5. Based on the response from 3 and 4, decide what is available for this user to enjoy.